# combine several .obj files using python

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, graphics, wavefront

I want to combine several `.obj` files using python. My data structure takes the following form.. for example here I put 3 values for each, namely, vertices-v, vertex normal-vn and faces-f;

**File1.obj**

```
v -4.56 8.89 1617.5
v -7.92 9.21 1217.33
v -5.71 9.97 1617.58

vn 0.95 0.15 0.23
vn 0.97 -0.21 0.035
vn 0.19 -0.62 -0.75

f 1//1 2//2 3//3
f 1//1 3//3 4//4
f 13//13 14//14 9//9
```

**File2.obj**

```
v -54.22 61.67 1604.59
v -54.36 62.53 1605.06
v -53.79 62.06 1605.55

vn -0.36 0.16 -0.15
vn -0.27 -0.46 -0.79
vn 0.58 -0.87 -0.06

f 216//216 182//182 162//162
f 226//226 182//182 216//216
f 182//182 226//226 218//218
```

I followed another post from stack-overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785215/how-to-merge-two-obj-files-after-texture-mapping-process)) to combine, but I do not really get it how to deal with the vertex normal data.

My combined file, something like this;

**combined.obj**

```
v -4.56 8.89 1617.5
v -7.92 9.21 1217.33
v -5.71 9.97 1617.58

v -54.22 61.67 1604.59
v -54.36 62.53 1605.06
v -53.79 62.06 1605.55

vn 0.95 0.15 0.23
vn 0.97 -0.21 0.035
vn 0.19 -0.62 -0.75

vn -0.36 0.16 -0.15
vn -0.27 -0.46 -0.79
vn 0.58 -0.87 -0.06

f 1//1 2//2 3//3
f 1//1 3//3 4//4
f 13//13 14//14 9//9

f 219//219 185//185 165//165 << ----
f 229//229 185//185 219//219 << ----
f 185//185 229//229 221//221 << ---- only these faces were manipulated(added 3, according to the description in the link)
```

I didn't change vertex and normal, only faces changed according to the post. The result is not as expected. If any idea/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Check & Correct the Original OBJ Files:**

Make sure that the original OBJ files are valid, and fix them if needed. A good documentation of the Wavefront OBJ file format can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) or [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/).

For example, it might be necessary to fix/remove faces with invalid indices, to remove duplicates, to check the vertex format etc. by hand or automated via script (e.g. with Python and [PyWavefront](https://pypi.org/project/PyWavefront/)), 3D editor (like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)) or a 3D conversion/clean-up tool (like [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net/)).

File1b.obj:

```
v -4.56 8.89 1617.5
v -7.92 9.21 1217.33
v -5.71 9.97 1617.58

vn 0.95 0.15 0.23
vn 0.97 -0.21 0.035
vn 0.19 -0.62 -0.75

f 1//1 2//2 3//3
#f 1//1 3//3 4//4 # invalid indices
#f 13//13 14//14 9//9 # invalid indices
```

File2b.obj:

```
v -54.22 61.67 1604.59
v -54.36 62.53 1605.06
v -53.79 62.06 1605.55

vn -0.36 0.16 -0.15
vn -0.27 -0.46 -0.79
vn 0.58 -0.87 -0.06

# indices changed like this: 162 -> 1, 182 -> 2, 216 -> 3, 218 -> 4, 226 -> 5
f 3//3 2//2 1//1
#f 5//5 2//2 3//3 # invalid indices
#f 2//2 5//5 4//4 # invalid indices
```

---

**Step 2: Combine Multiple OBJ Files:**

Combine the objects from the original files by simply editing the text manually or by using a script/tool or by importing them into a 3D editor one by one, and reexporting them into one combined file.

Result.obj:

```
# from File1b.obj
v -4.56 8.89 1617.5
v -7.92 9.21 1217.33
v -5.71 9.97 1617.58

# from File2b.obj
v -54.22 61.67 1604.59
v -54.36 62.53 1605.06
v -53.79 62.06 1605.55

# from File1b.obj
vn 0.95 0.15 0.23
vn 0.97 -0.21 0.035
vn 0.19 -0.62 -0.75

# from File2b.obj
vn -0.36 0.16 -0.15
vn -0.27 -0.46 -0.79
vn 0.58 -0.87 -0.06


# from File1b.obj
o MyObject1
f 1//1 2//2 3//3

# from File2b.obj -> offset of 3 added to all indices
o MyObject2
f 6//6 5//5 4//4

# or merged into one object:
#o MyObjectMerged1
#f 1//1 2//2 3//3
#f 6//6 5//5 4//4
```

---

*Note: This answer tries to solve the particular issue from the original question and ignores the mentioned Python-scripting specific aspects, since there was no reproducible example given.*

---